# How to add a different div in the samefile with jspdf

Tags: html, jspdf

I want to convert the other div with id="page2" in my html to an image and add it on another page in the same pdf file
this is my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function genPDF() {
       html2canvas(document.getElementById('hoja1'),{
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
         var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         var doc= new jsPDF();
         doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0,210,230);
         doc.save('ContratoMutuo.pdf');
        }
       });
     }
   </script>
```

but only work with one div

and the html code is:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>file</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function genPDF() {
                html2canvas(document.getElementById('hoja1'),{
                  onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                  var doc= new jsPDF();
                  doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0,50,50);
                  doc.save('test.pdf');
                 }
                });
              }
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id="hoja1">
                <TABLE WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=200>
                  <TD width=100 BGCOLOR="red">prueba </TD>
                  <TD WIDTH=100 BGCOLOR="yellow">prueba </TD>
                  <TD WIDTH=100 BGCOLOR="gray">prueba </TD>
                </TABLE>
            </div>
            <div id="hoja2">
              <TABLE WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=200>
                <TD width=100 BGCOLOR="green">prueba </TD>
                <TD WIDTH=100 BGCOLOR="blue">prueba </TD>
                <TD WIDTH=100 BGCOLOR="gray">prueba </TD>
              </TABLE>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript: genPDF()">DOWNLOAD PDF</a>
          </body>
        </html>
```

the complete file should be:

[1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktUmb.png)

and
[2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4gs.png)

in the same file please help!! thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly what are u trying to archive, this could work:

```
    function genPDF() {
                           html2canvas(document.getElementById('hoja1'),{
                             onrendered: function (canvas) {
                               html2canvas(document.getElementById('hoja2'),{
                                 onrendered: function (canvas2) {
                                 var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                                 var doc= new jsPDF();
                                 doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0,210,230);
                                 var img2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/png");
                                 doc.addPage();
                                 doc.addImage(img2,'JPEG',0,0,210,230);
                                 doc.save('ContratoMutuo.pdf');
                            }
                           });
                         }
                         });
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 captureScreen() {
  let dashboard :any=''
  let dashboard1 :any=''
  let doc = new jsPDF();
  //tab1
    dashboard = document.getElementById('tab1');
    let dashboardHeight = dashboard.clientHeight;
    let dashboardWidth = dashboard.clientWidth;
    let options = { pagesplit: true, background: 'white', width: dashboardWidth, height: dashboardHeight };
   //tab2
    dashboard1 = document.getElementById('tab2');
    let dashboardHeight1 = dashboard1.clientHeight;
    let dashboardWidth1 = dashboard1.clientWidth;
    let options1 = { pagesplit: true, background: 'white', width: dashboardWidth1, height: dashboardHeight1 };

  domtoimage.toPng(dashboard, options).then((imgData) => {
    domtoimage.toPng(dashboard1, options1).then((imgData1) => {
        doc = new jsPDF(dashboardWidth > dashboardHeight ? 'l' : 'p', 'mm', [dashboardWidth, dashboardHeight]);
       let imgProps = doc.getImageProperties(imgData);
       let pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
       let pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;   
       doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
       doc.addPage();
       doc.addImage(imgData1, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
       doc.save('analogue-finder.pdf');
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).